# What is the grammatical term for "Defense Minister" vs "Minister of Defense"?

Tags: grammar

There are lots of situations in English when you can either say "x-er/-ing of y" or "y x-ing/-er". Are there grammatical terms for these two forms?

Comment: Hello Doctor Bossman. Can you give examples of "x-er/-ing of y" and "y x-ing/-er"? I don't know what they mean or how they relate to your question.

Comment: Killer of birds vs bird killer, killing of birds vs bird killing minister of defense vs defense minister, ministry of defense vs defense ministry, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -er suffix indicates an [agent noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun). The -ing suffix indicates a [gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund). Using a noun to modify another noun is [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). While "minister" ends with "-er", there is no word "minist", so this is an odd case where there's a word that looks like an agent noun, but doesn't follow the same pattern of being a verb plus -er. It can be considered a noun form of "administer", but that already has -er.